# Composer - Unable to install github package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install [kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer](https://github.com/kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer) package but it keep requesting me to not install laravel/framework. 
The error looks something like this:

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer dev-master
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.0
    - This keeps going all the way to laravel/framework 7.0.1...

- Installation request for kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer dev-master 
-> satisfiable by kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.1 -> 
satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev,
 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev,
 v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20...all the way to v5.8.9
```

My composer.json looks something like this:

```
 "require": {
         "kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer": "dev-master",
        "php": "^7.3.16",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "hisorange/browser-detect": "^4.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",

    },
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer"
}],

    "require-dev": {
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
```

Can anyone help me out? 
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Which parts of that error message are unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The Package doesn't support in Laravel Version 7. I have check in packagist, that package support Laravel 5.4 or below.

So the solution is either you install other package or you downgrade your laravel version (try Laravel 5.8 first).

Here the packagist link 
https://packagist.org/packages/kirill-latish/laravel-sportmonks-soccer